# Probability Help! X and Y are geometric RV's with parameter p. What are ...

Tags: probability

a) $P\{X + Y = n\} (n = 1,2,...)$?

b) $P\{X = k | X + Y = n\} (1 ≤ k < n)$?

My work thus far...

a)

$\begin{align}P(X + Y = 1) & = P((X = 0 \cap Y = 1) \cup (X = 1 \cap Y = 0)) \\ & = P(X = 0)P(Y = 1)+P(X = 1)P(Y = 0) \\ ~ & = 2P(0)P(1) \\ ~ & = 2q p^2 \end{align}$

$\begin{align}P(X + Y = 2) & = P((X = 0 \cap Y = 2) \cup (X = 2\cap Y = 0)\cup (X = 1\cap Y = 1)) \\ ~ & = 2P(0)P(2) + P(1)P(1) \\ ~ & = 2(p^2)(q^2) + (q^2)(p^2) \\ ~ & = 3(q^2)(p^2) \end{align}$

Does this seem like I'm on the correct path... Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It looks correct (for the count of failures geometric progression).  It's just not general enough.

Comment: @GrahamKemp So do I need to do a summation in the general sense for the probabilities? I am having trouble figuring out how I would compute the sum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **shifted geometric distribution**, of $X$ failures before success on trial $X+1$, $X\sim\mathcal{SGeo}(p)\iff \Pr(X=x)=p(1-p)^x$

$\begin{align} \text{Given: } & X\bot Y, X\sim\mathcal{SGeo}(p), Y\sim\mathcal{SGeo}(p) 
\\ \Pr(X+Y=n) & = \Pr\left(\bigcup\limits_{x=0}^{n} (X=x\cap Y= n-x)\right) & \forall n\in\{0..\infty\}
\\ ~ & = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{n} \Pr(X=x)\Pr(Y=n-x)
\\ ~ & = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{n} p(1-p)^x\cdot p(1-p)^{n-x}
\\ ~ & = (n+1)p^2(1-p)^n
\\ ~ & ~
\\ \Pr(X=k\mid X+Y=n) & = \dfrac{\Pr(X=k\cap X+Y=n)}{\Pr(X+Y=n)} & \forall n\in\{0..\infty\}, k\in\{0..n\}
\\ ~ & = \text{et cetera}
\end{align}$

---

For the **geometric distribution** of $X-1$ failures before success on trial $X$, $X\sim\mathcal{Geo}(p)\iff \Pr(X=x)=p(1-p)^{x-1}$

$\begin{align} \text{Given: } & X\bot Y, X\sim\mathcal{Geo}(p), Y\sim\mathcal{Geo}(p)
\\ \Pr(X+Y=n) & = \Pr\left(\bigcup\limits_{x=1}^{n-1} (X=x\cap Y= n-x)\right) & \forall n\in\{2..\infty\}
\\ ~ & = \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n-1} \Pr(X=x)\Pr(Y=n-x)
\\ ~ & = \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n-1} p(1-p)^{x-1}\cdot p(1-p)^{n-x-1}
\\ ~ & = (n-1)p^2(1-p)^{n-2}
\\ ~ & ~
\\ \Pr(X=k\mid X+Y=n) & = \dfrac{\Pr(X=k\cap X+Y=n)}{\Pr(X+Y=n)} & \forall n\in\{2..\infty\}, k\in\{1..n-1\}
\\ ~ & = \text{et cetera}
\end{align}$

Comment: Is that last step of $Pr(X+Y = n) = (n-1)p^2(1-p)^n$? because $n-(-1)-1 = n$

Comment: @user161154 Nope.  $(x-1)+(n-x-1) = n+x-x-1-1 = n-2$, there is no subtraction of a negative involved (there's no $-(-1)$ term).

Comment: Okay now I see. So with the last part do we get that $Pr(X = k| X + Y = n) = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} Pr(X=k)Pr(Y=n-k)}{(n-1)p^2(1-p)^{n-2}} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} p(1-p)^{k-1} \cdot p(1-p)^{n-k+1}}{(n-1)p^2(1-p)^{n-2}}$ ?

Comment: @user161154 No, the numerator isn't a sum. $\Pr(X=k\mid X+Y=n) = \frac{ p (1-p)^{k-1} \cdot p (1-p)^{n-1-k} }{ (n-1) p^2 (1-p)^{n-2} }$ Which simplifies down nicely.  The result isn't surprising when you think about it.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  Without this assumption, it is not possible to answer your question without further information.

You have the right idea, but doing the calculation for each $n$ is clearly going to take a while.  So, you have to be a little more clever:  Suppose we let $Z = X+Y$.  We wish to find $\Pr[Z = n]$.  Note that we can write $$\Pr[Z = n] = \sum_{y=0}^n \Pr[(X = n-y) \cap (Y = y)] = \sum_{y=0}^n \Pr[X = n-y]\Pr[Y = y].$$  Now you know what each of these probabilities is, so write them out, and calculate the sum.

Comment: Sorry I am confused as to what we would do from your last step. How do we know the probabilities?